# HighCharts decimal point shape on ToolTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for my two similar projects. For some reason, decimal point shape is different for both on tooltip. For one, it as it should be i.e. 'CIRCLE'. For the other one, it is a 'SQUARE'. Both are shown below 
 This is for the square decimal point

[[image]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruE6X.png)

 
Below image is for circle decimal point.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what is wrong with those tooltips?

Comment: you seem to be using different fonts for each tooltip

Comment: @SebastianWędzel   the decimal point is of different shape in both images, if you look at it closely, one is circle and other one is more of a rectangle

Comment: @UsamaAlvi Are you sure that `tooltip` config and font is the same for both charts? Could you reproduce your case on some online editor?